# What is the physical meaning of Floquet quasi-energy? (to a near-layman)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, floquet-theory

I am doing a project for my undergrad physics course "Mathematical Methods in Physics". In the project, I need to write a computer program to calculate and plot graphs about Rabi oscillations. I am able to do the programming side of things, but I do not understand the physics behind it.

In the project, we examine a simplified case of 1 atom coupled to a time-dependent electric field in a two-level system. In the process of solving it, we construct a Floquet Hamiltonian matrix to find the quasi-energies (of which there are 2). We then plot the quasi-energies against the difference between the ground state energy and the excited state energy.

I do not understand the physical meaning of the quasi-energies. Could you please explain the physical meaning of the quasi-energies to a physics undergrad who only has very introductory knowledge to quantum physics?

Edit: Below are some more detailed information.

For the first question, the Hamiltonian is
$$
H(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
\hbar\omega_0/2 & E\cos(\omega t) \\
E\cos(\omega t) & - \hbar\omega_0/2
\end{bmatrix}\,.
$$

where $\hbar\omega_0$ is the difference in energies between the two states, $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the incident light beam, and $E$ is the overall inference from the applied light (which should be comparable to $\hbar\omega$).

And the corresponding Floquet Hamiltonian is
[image: The first question's Floquet Hamiltonian]

From the Floquet Hamiltonian, I am able to find a number of quasi-energies. Out of those quasi-energies, I isolate exactly 2 quasi-energies that satisfy this condition:
$$
-\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}<\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2 <\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\,.
$$
I then successfully plot out the value of these 2 quasi-energies against the difference in ground state and excited state energies. Here is a plot I made (I entered arbitrary values for the variables):
[image: Example of a plot of quasi-energy against the difference in ground state and excited state energies]

There is also a second question, where the Hamiltonian is now changed to
$$
H(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
\hbar\omega_0/2 & E\cos(\omega t) + E'\cos(5\omega t) \\
E\cos(\omega t)+ E'\cos(5\omega t) & - \hbar\omega_0/2
\end{bmatrix}\,.
$$
And with this second Hamiltonian, the above-mentioned plot becomes:
[image: The second question's plot]

My problem here is that I do not know the physical meaning of the quasi-energies, and thus I do not know how to interpret these plots. Our professor mentioned something about hybridization as well, which I guess has something to do with the quasi-energies. I tried Googling about hybridization and Floquet quasi-energies, but I think the search results were too advanced for me.

Comment: Are you sure there were only two quasi-energies? In Floquet solutions, there should be an *infinite* number of quasi-energies, separated by integer multiples of $\hbar\omega$, where $\omega$ is the drive-frequency.  These collapse down onto just two "real" energies, but that's partly where the interpretation lies. Can you edit your post to include the Hamiltonian that you are using? That would help as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, march! I have edited in more information.

Comment: I'm new to this topic as well, so I just post a comment waiting for someone to answer. In your case there are two Floquet eigenstates of the system, $\Psi_{\alpha}(t) = e^{-i\varepsilon_{\alpha}t} u_{\alpha}(t)$, where $\alpha=1,2$ and $u_{\alpha}(t)$ is time periodic. The system is in general in a superposition of these states, resulting in the interference pattern of the two: the quasienergies determine the relative phase of the two waves, thus controlling the interference pattern.

Comment: Maybe you're more familiar with the notion of Bloch wave vectors. But floquet's theorem is really just a generalization of Bloch's theorem. You can think of the quasi energies the same way people think of the Bloch momentum, just in time instead of space.

Comment: Thanks Matteo and Wihtedeka! I can understand Matteo's summary. As for Wihtedeka's, I'm afraid I've never learnt Bloch wave vectors, but thank you for your help!